# Como mostrar cada letra con retraso de un segundo?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de realizar un ejercicio en el que debo de enseñar una palabra escrita dentro de una tabla, pero debo hacer que no se muestren todas las letras de un principio sino primero al cargar la pagina H, tras un segundo O,un segundo mas L y por ultimo otro segundo A.
He conseguido que se vea la palabra en la tabla pero no logro saber como seria para que funcione, he tratado de setear lo segundos pero no logro ver que hago mal y porque no me funciona. Gracias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ejercicio 2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            tr, td{
                text-align: center;
                padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="saludo()">
        <table border=2 >
            <tr>
                <td  id="primero"></td>
                <td id="segundo"></td>
                <td  id="tercero"></td>
                <td  id="quarto"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            function saludo() {
                var h = document.getElementById("primero").innerHTML = "H";
                var o = document.getElementById("segundo").innerHTML = "O";
                var l = document.getElementById("tercero").innerHTML = "L";
                var a = document.getElementById("quarto").innerHTML = "A";

                o.setSeconds(1);
                l.setSeconds(2);
                a.setSeconds(3);
                
                var saludo = h+o.setSeconds(1)+l.setSeconds(2)+a.setSeconds(3);
                
                return saludo;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: setSeconds() es una función que pertenece a la clase Date() y no se usa para "configurar" la velocidad en la que se muestra un objeto en javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ejercicio 2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            tr, td{
                text-align: center;
                padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="saludo()">
        <table border=2 >
            <tr>
                <td  id="primero"></td>
                <td id="segundo"></td>
                <td  id="tercero"></td>
                <td  id="quarto"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            function saludo() {
            
               // guardar los elementos en un arreglo
                let elementos = [
                
                   document.getElementById("primero"),
                   document.getElementById("segundo"),
                   document.getElementById("tercero"),
                   document.getElementById("quarto")
                
                ];
            
                // crear un arreglo con las letras del saludo
                let saludo = ['h','o','l','a'];
                // contador de la letra a mostrar
                let i = 0;
                
                let interval = 
                // la función se interval toma una función
                // y la ejecuta según el tiempo especificado
                setInterval(()=>{
                  // asignar la letra en posición i del saludo
                  // al elemento en posición i
                  elementos[i].innerHTML = saludo[i++];
                  // si ya se terminó el arreglo 
                  // limpiar el interval
                  if(i == saludo.length) clearInterval(interval);
                },1000);
               
               
               
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```